# don't have function startAccelerometerUpdateQueue in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, accelerometer, sensors

Does Someone know why in my xCode there isn't function startAccelerometerUpdateQueue? Here there is a screenshot of my xCode:
[Screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRiGa.png)

I thought maybe the function was deprecated, so I selected the function starAccelerometerUpdate. But when i try to insert the NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), xCode doesn't see that too (it suggests to change NSOperationQueue in OperationQueue, but i need the function mainQueue(). [Screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjdYm.png)

Comment: In Swift 3 the **NS** prefix was dropped, so NSOperationQueue is now OperationQueue. The function you want is the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading old documentation or an old tutorial. The method was renamed in Swift 3's "Grand Renaming". The second version you tried is close, (`startAccelerometerUpdate(to: handler:)`) but `NSOperationQueue` is now `OperationQueue`. It should look like this:

```
motionManager.startGyroUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) { (data, error) in
    // Your handler code here
}
```